# USB device communication in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, usb, device

I have an old USB remote control receiver originally for Win XP, which's included SW doesn't run on Win10 anymore. But for its HW is still driver available for Win10, therefore I'd like try to use it from an own SW, but I have no experience with HW communication under W10 UWP (C# app). I read some articles, but this HW part of Win is not easy, I hope somebody with required skills will immediately see what I did wrong and can advise what to do.

I see the device listed in the in the device manager, the drivers are installed, the device seems to be OK.
I can also detect its connection/disconnection on the USB port via DeviceWatcher class. I know its device Id. Using that ID I'm trying to open it, but no success. Because I don't know exactly what type it has, I tried everything which could make sense: RFComm, Serial Device, Usb Device, HID device, Custom Device, but no success. Its "parts" are listed in the HID and the USB sections of the device manager, but also HidDevice and UsbDevice classes always return NULL. I tried to run form the UI thread, non UI thread, the same. I tried to call the class creation several times (I read for somebody the first attempt always returned NULL, but for the 2nd it was successful, but for me didn't help). I also experimented a lot with the packaging manifest's device capability section, no success. I also experimented with the desired access and sharing mode, no success. Bellow is my code and my app manifest. What am I doing wrong?

```cs
                    string devId = @"\\?\USB#VID_0BC7&PID_0004#5&4bbb90c&0&1#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}";
                    var hid1 = await Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.HidDevice.FromIdAsync(devId, Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                    var usb1 = await Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(devId);
                    var bt1 = await Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm.RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(devId);
                    var ser1 = await Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(devId);
                    var sens1 = await Windows.Devices.Sensors.Custom.CustomSensor.FromIdAsync(devId);
                    var cust1 = await Windows.Devices.Custom.CustomDevice.FromIdAsync(devId, Windows.Devices.Custom.DeviceAccessMode.Read, Windows.Devices.Custom.DeviceSharingMode.Shared);
```

The manifest:

```xml
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="usb">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="interfaceId:a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="interfaceId:a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
    <DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="interfaceId:a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
    <DeviceCapability Name="sensors.custom">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="interfaceId:a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed"></DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

HID, RFComm, USB, Serial return null, Sensor return a range exception, CustomDevice return an access denied exception.

Comment: Hi, Please make sure the device id is correct and provide your system version. It is also recommended that you modify your Capability according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/updating-the-app-manifest-with-usb-device-capabilities) and that the attribute `Type="interfaceId:"` is not found in the documentation.

Comment: The device ID is correct, it's taken from the output of the DeviceWatcher class. Using win32 CreateFile() is possible to open it. My system version is Win10 1903. The Capability section I've created is only experimental, to be honest I have no idea what to put there in my case. Because it depends on the device type, what I don't know. Assuming I know only the device ID, what's the generic approach to start a conversation with the device? Is it possible to deduce from the ID what should go into the Capability configuration?

Comment: Hi Robert, you need to add the vid & pid in `DeviceCapability` like `<Device Id="vidpid:0BC7 0004">
    <Function Type="name:vendorSpecific"/>
  </Device>`